# Changing of MAC Address with Network Manager on Debian 10

Tags: debian, syslog, mac-address

Looking at syslog files on Debian 10 form a previous session I have noticed a MAC Address change and I do not know why it is happening. Any ideas on how to stop this?

```
Jun  8 15:43:46 NetworkManager[729]: <info>  [1591623826.4785] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun  8 15:43:46 NetworkManager[729]: <info>  [1591623826.4790] device (wlp8s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  8 15:43:46 dbus-daemon[727]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=729 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Jun  8 15:43:46 NetworkManager[729]: <info>  [1591623826.4793] device (wlp8s0): set-hw-addr: **reset MAC address to 68:5D:43:61:77:45** (unmanage)
Jun  8 15:43:46 NetworkManager[729]: <info>  [1591623826.4799] device (enp7s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  8 15:43:46  kernel: [15194.894941] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
Jun  8 15:43:46  kernel: [15194.895237] RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet r8169-700:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-700:00, irq=IGNORE)
Jun  8 15:43:46  systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun  8 15:43:46  dbus-daemon[727]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun  8 15:43:46 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun  8 15:43:46  nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enp7s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jun  8 15:43:46  nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enp7s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jun  8 15:43:46 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Jun  8 15:43:46 NetworkManager[729]: <info>  [1591623826.6955] device (wlp8s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  8 15:43:46  kernel: [15195.108815] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
Jun  8 15:43:46  kernel: [15195.110559] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp8s0: link is not ready
Jun  8 15:43:46  NetworkManager[729]: <info>  [1591623826.6963] device (wlp8s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to **DE:5B:91:11:04:52** (scanning)
Jun  8 15:43:46 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
```

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address is being randomized. See [Randomize your MAC address using NetworkManager](https://fedoramagazine.org/randomize-mac-address-nm/)

Note that a random MAC address is generated when scanning for wifi networks (because your MAC address can be sniffed over the air by anybody), and another address can be generated when the connection with an access point is established.

Have you looked at your configuration file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (or subdirectories)  If you don't like the behavior you could still use spoofed but 'stable' addresses for certain connections like your home network.

You can also edit Network Manager connections and assign a value to the 'cloned mac address' field.